# Removing segment from circle?

Tags: qgis-3, vector-layer, circle

I have drawn a vector circle with `"Add circle from 2 points"`.

How do I remove a segment of this circle? In essence, I want to edit a circle and convert it into an arc.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create centroid
2. Edit with snapping enabled
3. Reshape features

[image]

Comment: You show how to edit a disk, my understanding is that the question is about circle (line vs polygon).